# Creating mobile jQuery Toggle menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mobile, toggle

I'm trying to make an jQuery toggle menu for a mobile website.
Since it is a wordpress site I would like to make this as dynamic as possible.  I want to create a custom WordPress menu.

Now the tricky part comes.
I want it to check if the menu item has children (or child ul) and then toggle between:

`<div class="plus">+</div>` and `<div class="min">-</div>`.

When a item has no childeren nothing should happen at all.

So far I've managed to do this, please see my experiment at http://jsfiddle.net/jfvandekamp/9Dvrr/2/

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers yet?

Comment: SOrry was goine for a couple a days (holidays) but thanks a million times man! i just couldn't figure it out and i used your versin of de jsfiddle. I chacnges de preppend to append for placing the span behind de content.

Comment: Please be aware that the jsFiddle example is just that: an example. You are wise not to use it as-is. Also, if your problem is solved, you should consider marking the question as answered.

Comment: I will, thanks for the advice! i have it working on my webserver the way you mentioned. Made a litte change myself (http://jsfiddle.net/9Dvrr/7/)
I'm trying to make a if else for displaying a <span> > </span> when the + or - is nog displayed. Since this item has no children it will be a straightforward item. Been experimenting again http://jsfiddle.net/9Dvrr/6/ but isn't working the way i want it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery function $.contains() to Check to see if a DOM element is within another DOM element.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

So in your example, you'd check to see if the menu item that was clicked contains another UL element

`$jQuery.contains($(this), '<ul>');`

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`$.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to filter out the collapsible items.

I've updated your jsFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/9Dvrr/5/**

Comment: Thanks a thousand times! this did exactly what i needed!